# Inequality Methods

Tags: inequality

If I were to prove:
$$A\geq B$$

but we can only prove that: 
$$A\geq C$$ and $$ B\leq D$$
Is showing that  $$C\geq D$$
enough to prove the original inequality? or are there assumptions that have to be met?

Comment: `\geq` and `\leq` produce $\geq$ and $\leq$ respectively

Comment: So, you want to prove that $A\geq B$.  Your assumptions are that $A\geq C$ that $C\geq D$ and that $D\geq B$.  Yes, those three hypotheses are enough to prove the desired inequality.  Remember that $\geq$ is an example of a partial order, and partial orders are [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $A \ge C \ge D \ge B$.